# S2D - How to reclaim space?

Tags: storage-spaces-direct

I have a Windows Server 2016 failover cluster with storage based on S2D (Storage Spaces Direct).
I recently noticed that if I delete something (VHDX files of virtual machines) the space of the deleted items is not reclaimed.
For example before deleting 500GB VHDX file I had 200GB free and after deleting that VHDX file I still have 200GB free.
Two questions:

1. Is it normal for S2D?
2. How to reclaim free space?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks@BaronSamedi1958.
So eventually free space will be reclaimed? I would rather avoid playing with PS cmdlets as this S2D turned out to be extremely fragile and highly unreliable. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there’s sort of a delay in seeing your freed space back.

Try these PowerShell cmd-lets:

```
Optimize-StoragePool -FriendlyName "POOL_NAME"

Optimize-Volume -DriveLetter <DRIVE_LETTER:> -ReTrim -SlabConsolidate
```

You should see results immediately.